# Jackson passing null value to constructor

Tags: json, jackson

Considering a Java class constructor that take two parameters but allows the second to be null.

```java
public class Category {
    String name;
    @JsonIgnore Category parent;
    Category(String name,Category parent){this.name = name;this.parent=parent;}
}
```

I skipped the serialization of parent with @JsonIgnore annotation because I don't need it. Now Jackson is not capable to deserialize it because it don't find the parent property in the resulting Jason.

Is there any another solution but to define a constructor taking only the name parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to have named constructor parameters that are missing -- you will simply get null instead of value. So you could just have:

```
@JsonCreator
public Category(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("whatever") Category parent) { ... }
```

and whatever is found is passed. No exception will be thrown; Jackson never requires a property to exist. It just complains about things it does not recognize (unless configured not to).